# Hackerrank Kangroo Problem- Return not working (undefined)

Tags: javascript, arrays

i am going through one of the Hackerrank problem, i have having issue when i return it is showing as undefined, although some of the testcase it passes when the condition fulfils to "NO", bascially i have to check the condition and return either Yes or No as string.

Any suggestion please where i am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

link to photo showing the error[undefine error on hackerrank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Omt9L.png)
hackerrank link to the problem is : [hackerrank problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/kangaroo/problem)
Snippet of code that i wrote is,

```js
// Complete the kangaroo function below.
function kangaroo(x1, v1, x2, v2) {

  let xf1 = x1 + v1
  let xf2 = x2 + v2
  let i = 0;
  let z1 = "YES";
  let z2 = "NO";
  let z;
  let s = [];


  for (i; i < 2; i++) {

    s[i] = xf2 - xf1

    xf1 = xf1 + v1
    xf2 = xf2 + v2

  }



  if (s[1] < s[0]) {


    xf1 = xf1 + v1
    xf2 = xf2 + v2
    let d = 1

    while (s[d] > 0) {
      d++
      s[d] = xf2 - xf1


      if (s[d] = 0) z = z1;
      else if (s[d] < 0) z = z2;

      xf1 = xf1 + v1
      xf2 = xf2 + v2
    }

  } else z = z2;

  return z;
}
```

Comment: If you're getting undefined then I guess you're managing to miss all the cases where you set z. Could you indent your code properly? That might make it easier to see what's happening.

Comment: At first glance this could happen if s[0]>=0 and s[1]==0, but I haven't read the problem carefully enough to know if that's possible.

Comment: `if (s[d] = 0)` is an **assignment** not comparison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function kangaroo(x1, v1, x2, v2) {

 // check if kangaroo 1 or 2 is even able to catch up
 // if cangaroo 1 is behind cangaroo 2 AND if cangaroo 1 has a smaller jump wide then cangaroo 2 then cangaroo 1 is not able to catch up. Same logic for cangaroo 2

 if(x1 < x2 && v1 <= v2) return "NO";
 if(x2 < x1 && v2 <= v1) return "NO";
 

 // check if both cangaroo stand on the same starting point
 if(x1 === x2) return "YES";

 // check witch kangaroo need to catch up and loop till  the kangaroo catch up.
 if(x1 < x2) {
    while(x1 < x2) {
       x1 += v1;
       x2 += v2;
    }
 }
 else {
    while(x2 < x1) {
       x1 += v1;
       x2 += v2;
    }
 }
   
 // kangaroo catched up, now check if they are at the same position.
 if(x1 == x2) return "YES";
 return "NO";


}

let result = kangaroo(...[0, 2, 5, 3]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @AlonEitan i have commented it, is it enough?